# How to set PDF compatibility to "Acrobat 5 (PDF 1.4)"

Tags: pdftex, pdf

My Master's Thesis is going to be printed at a printing office, and they have requested the compatibility of the PDF to be "Acrobat 5 (PDF 1.4)". How can this be defined?

Comment: Put `\pdfminorversion=4` in your preamble. This will set the version to 1.4. But the output will be the very same as always. The default for LaTeX is 1.5 and therefore you will get an 1.5 PDF which prints 1.4 as version. If you know any concrete constraints which make 1.5 PDFs incompatible here, please let us know about that cases.

Comment: Btw. this constraint is a bit strange for a printing office. PDF 1.4 has been the standard from 2001 to 2003 (acc. to Wikipedia). Maybe you should tell them, that you will deliver a 1.5 (2003-2004) and expect them to handle this. If they stick to this constraint, I would look for another office. If their software is that old, they might destroy your nice figures or alike. Just an advice.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi This qualifies as an answer in my opinion, not as a comment.

Comment: @phx Thanks, but until now, I do not know what the word "compatibility" means to the OP. My comment is just a trick to make them think it is ok. If the OP includes `.jp2`, `.mpg` or `.mp3` files, this will compile properly, it will look like a 1.4 PDF, but will not be compatible with Adobe 5.

Comment: The printing office is decided by the university. All I do is to upload the PDF to a university webpage, and the thesis is printet (free). Though I find it strange that they prefer PDF 1.4.  They also told me to avoid transparent figures and to import figures based on PDF. So I have to change all figures from PDF to PNG. I think it's weird, but I guess it is based on the software they have, and the experience they've had previous years. The pressing office handles all Master Theses from the University.

Comment: What, you can't include pdf in your pdf? That is ridiculous. Also it should make no difference to include a pdf figure and produce it directly in LaTeX, I think? No transparent stuff I can at least understand somewhat, as that is sometimes a problem for the pdf viewer (which is quite sad).

Comment: @ROLF Just include your images as `.pdf` or `.png` and do not use fancy stuff as described above. Then you should be safe with my method. Please let me know, if this is fine for you and I make it an answer.

Comment: Another ---non-LaTeX--- solution would be to use Acrobat to set it to the correct compability. That should also check for non conformant features and if possible convert or remove them.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi: I've substituted the PDFs with PNG, and added `\pdfminorversion=4` to the preamble. I couldn't see any difference :).